# How to push my local project into an empty repository?

Tags: git, github

How to push a code from my local env to a brand new repository that does not have any branch yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to add a new [remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) to your repository? Or are you asking if [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) can be used to push to a remote repository directly?

Comment: the second option. Git push to a remote repository directly.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is:

> git push [options] [ […​]]

Repository can be a URL to a repository or the name of a configured *remote* in your repo.

To push local branch "a" to a repository at example.com/repo.git, execute

```
git push example.com/repo.git a
```

If you plan on doing that more than once, consider adding a remote:

```
git remote add examplerepo example.com/repo.git
git push examplerepo a
```